# Nginx permissions on access log rotation

Tags: nginx, devops

`access.log` is created as the `root` user. When this fills up, `nginx` rotates it and creates a new one.

```
-rw-r----- 1 nginx    adm   306753808 Mar 15 15:47 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root 1197875535 Mar 15 06:25 access.log.1
```

However the new one is created with the `nginx` user as privileged. This becomes a problem when an agent needs to read off this log file.

How do I set this so that when it rotates log it creates it with `root` or atleast have a different symbolic value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your /etc/logrotate.d/nginx if you have a line to set the right user and group permissions like this (line 2):

```
# cat -n /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
1    /var/log/nginx/*log {
2    create 0644 nginx adm
3    daily
4    rotate 10
5    missingok
6    notifempty
7    compress
8    sharedscripts
9    postrotate
10      /bin/kill -USR1 `cat /run/nginx.pid 2>/dev/null` 2>/dev/null || true
11   endscript
12 }
```